# How to get variable value from string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have variable in string format as follows:

```
"hello?supporterId=57d7466d"
```

I want to extract the value of supporterId and hello text from above string as follows:

```
text="hello"
supporterId="57d7466d"
```

How to achieve this in javascript?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: use `split` or `regEx`

Comment: If this string is part of an url, you can use `URLSearchParams` and the `window.location` properties to extract the info without having to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by splitting the string,

```
var test = "hello?supporterId=57d7466d"
var text = test.split('?')[0];
var supportID = test.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Split string by `?` or `=` delimiter and select first and last item of result array using `slice()`

```js
var str = "hello?supporterId=57d7466d";

var split = str.split(/\?|=/);
[text, supporterId] = [split[0], split[2]]
console.log(text, supporterId);
```

Comment: I was looking for supporterId value